# ASP.NET MVC 3 best practice / design

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have spent a lot of time searching for best practices for designing a ASP.NET MVC 3 web site using EF 4.1 or another ORM. I found this [tutorial on Implementing the Repository and Unit of Work Patterns in an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) . It was a good tutorial and I learned something. So this got me thinking and wanted to know from the people on stack is this something you would use? if not why and how did you design your web site? I just want to learn the correct way to do things and understand why one way is better then the other.

Comment: All those abstractions are done to address particular set of requirements. So those abstractions may not be suitable for your requirements. The question is too generic. Provide more details of your domain, requirements, constraints, etc

Comment: This is more of a general question. I really want to understand when and why you would pick the approach like the one in the tutorial and what other options are out there.

Comment: Discussing design choices without the context is useless.

Answer (score 2):

First to say Entity Framework implements a Repository pattern and a Unit of Work Pattern. Implementing Repository and Unit of Work patterns on top of a modern ORM like Entity framework is an additional layer of abstraction that:

- narrows the possibilities of the underlying ORM
- does not provide additional value to the underlying ORM
- is at best worthless but may be harmful

One purpose of such implementations is to encapsulate the query logic in the Repository and not one query like Single Responsibility Principle ([SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)) would suggest, but a couple of queries and thus violating SRP. What you could do is to rely on your ORM and encapsulate extensive query logic in single Query classes.

My suggestion is not to please "best practices" by adding abstraction layers on abstraction  layers and so on but to try to solve a problem using some more general design guidelines such as [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).

Ayende Rahien reviews the Northwind Starter Kit application in a series of blog posts ([here](http://ayende.com/blog/153059/northwind-starter-kit-review-if-you-wonrsquo-t-respect-the-database-there-will-be-pain), [here](http://ayende.com/blog/153699/ask-ayende-repository-for-abstracting-multiple-data-sources), [here](http://ayende.com/blog/153153/northwind-starter-kit-review-refactoring-to-an-actual-read-model), [here](http://ayende.com/blog/153058/northwind-starter-kit-review-data-access-review-thoughts), [here](http://ayende.com/blog/153057/northwind-starter-kit-review-the-parents-have-eaten-sour-grapes-and-the-childrenrsquo-s-teeth-are-set-on-edge), [here](http://ayende.com/blog/153029/northwind-starter-kit-review-data-access-and-the-essence-of-needless-work-part-ii), [here](http://ayende.com/blog/153028/northwind-starter-kit-review-data-access-and-the-essence-of-needless-work-part-i) and [here](http://ayende.com/blog/152706/application-review-northwind-starter-kit)) in [his blog](http://ayende.com/blog) that deal with so called best practices applied in an application. This is a great read!

Comment: Thanks I will check out the blog. It really comes down to understanding when to use a best practice/ pattern and why.

Comment: -1 for repository pattern being "worthless" when used with "modern ORM"

Comment: The statement "is at best worthless but may be harmful" has to be seen in context of implementing a Repository pattern AND Unit of Work pattern on top of Entity Framework...

Comment: -1 because Entity Framework does not implement neither repository nor Unit of Work patterns